# How do I get a count of errors and warnings from gcc and g++?

Tags: gcc, emacs, compiler-errors, g++

I've skimmed through the `$ man gcc` and `$ man g++` but haven't found something that would print the error and warning counts. But I see that Emacs can print the error counts *and* warning counts in the `*compilation*` buffer. So, there must be an option in `gcc` and `g++` that I'm missing, cause I don't think Emacs would itself implement error count, that's just too much work.

> How do I get a count of errors and warnings from gcc and g++?

Comment: Why do you think it's too muck work? ISTM, this could be implemented with a `grep | wc` one-liner...

Comment: If you are really curious, you could `strace` your emacs and see how exactly it invokes the compiler. Another approach of course would be reading emacs' sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to count errors in `gcc`, because usually it runs on one file at a time and a project is usually many files, so there are many invocations of `gcc` to build a project.  Potentially there are many errors in different files so it makes sense that whatever runs `gcc` (e.g. `make`, or in turn Emacs which runs `make`) should keep track of the errors.  Indeed, when you run `M-x compile`, Emacs is the thing counting the errors.  Open `compile.el` (`M-x find-library RET compile RET`) and look at the variable `compilation-num-errors-found`, which is what gets added to the mode line (along with similar counts for warnings and infos).  It's not super straightforward how those variables get updated, but ultimately it's just matching regexps on the compiler output.