# How do I get an error and warning count from GHC/Cabal/Stack?

Tags: bash, haskell, compiler-errors, ghc, haskell-stack

If I run `dotnet build` in PowerShell to build a .NET project, at the end of the output, I see a message that tells me how many warnings and errors the compiler generated while building my project. I have attached an example below.

[image: dotnet build output snippet indicating warning and error count]

How can I get an error count with GHC? I am using stack, which uses cabal, which in turn uses GHC. A solution at any of those levels is fine.

I can get counts of the warnings or errors by piping the standard error of `stack build` into vim and using some search functionality in vim. However, I do not always get the correct results. When my source code or source file names contain the word "warning" or the word "error", the results of my search include false positives.

I would like a simple way to get the exact error and warning count. Perhaps, there is a command line flag or a simple wrapper that I can use? I looked through the man page for GHC and found no flag for error and/or warning counts.

I have read [this similar stack overflow post for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971278/how-do-i-get-a-count-of-errors-and-warnings-from-gcc-and-g). The answer to that question is not very encouraging, but I am curious if anyone else has some insight to share, and I am hoping GHC has a different story.

NOTE: I am using bash as my shell, so please gear any shell scripting towards bash.

Comment: Try `ghc -ddump-json OTHER_ARGS | grep Error | wc -l`. Might need tweaking based on what you find out the output looks like.

Comment: @alias Thanks, that is helpful. There are a few things that I still would like to circumvent:
1. Errors are printed to standard error, so that pipe doesn't actually redirect ghc's output to grep (can be worked around with `|&`, though.)
2. If I pipe standard output and error into grep, the error messages no longer show in the terminal. I have to either save the output and errors of ghc or try to compile the code twice when there are errors/warnings.
3. Like I said in the question's text, "If my source code contains the words 'warning' or 'error', the results of my search could be affected."

Comment: You definitely need something smarter.. You should pipe to a proper JSON parser and count the number of nodes for instance. Regarding you no longer see the errors in the terminal: I'm afraid that's not something you can avoid: You either have to run twice, or figure out a way to pretty-print the json yourself. Perhaps the best course of action is to file a request with GHC so they can give you an option to print the required info.

Comment: The non-json error format should also be useful enough to count errors I'd expect. A regex like `^.*:\d+:\d+: error:` should not have that many false positives.

Comment: @alias I have found that I was slightly wrong in my earlier comment. When I use the -ddump-json flag with ghc, the dumped JSON is printed to standard output. However, when I use stack, that output is redirected to standard error, and when building a medium-sized project, I got absolutely nothing printed to standard output. I'm not sure if cabal does the same or not: haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`-ddump-json`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/debugging.html#ghc-flag--ddump-json) flag to produce output as JSON and then use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to filter based on severity. Finally, you have the good old `wc -l` for counting. This is how you get the number of errors, for example:

```
ghc Main.hs -ddump-json | jq 'select(.severity == "SevError") .severity' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Some extra processing is required for stack, though. Per my 2nd comment on the question itself, stack redirects all of the standard output of ghc to standard error. If I pipe standard output and error into jq, then jq fails with parse errors. This is because stack adds extra messages like "Building all executables for my-project-name once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified
executables will be rebuilt." Most, if not all of those messages need to be filtered out, so that jq can do its thing. As a hack, I have used grep "^{".